# Plugin dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Consider following scenario. There are three plugins: pluginA, pluginB and pluginC. PluginA has a dependency on pluginB and re-exports it. PluginC wants to utilize pluginB and has dependency on pluginA. Since there is dependency pluginC -> pluginA -> pluginB, does pluginC need to add pluginB as its dependency?

I believe that it shouldn't. However, if I add direct dependency pluginC -> pluginB everything works fine, but if I remove that dependency and just leave pluginC -> pluginA, then I get errors stating that classes from pluginB cannot be found. Under what circumstances would I get these errors? Does it depend on the types of plugins (UI vs non-UI)?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transitive dependency (C depends on A depends on B) does work; I just tested a simple case to make sure. Make certain that PluginB is exporting whatever packages PluginC is trying to use. If that's not the problem, maybe you can update the question with more detail about the errors.

In general, I avoid using the re-export feature because it is less explicit and can introduce unintended dependencies (or at least, dependencies that you are not aware of). Instead, I either make all dependencies explicit (PluginC would depend on PluginB directly) or use Imported Packages instead (which doesn't care what plugin the packages come from, just that they have to be available from somewhere); it's more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I want to make dependency C -> A -> B is because other plugins might want to use plugin C, so my plugin A is a common plugin that has dependencies that other plugins can use. So let's say Commom Plugin depends on XML Utils Plugin and IO Plugin; plugins X, Y and Z just need to add Common Plugin as their dependency in order to use XML Utils and IO Plugins. Hence the whole re-export approach. I understand how unwanted dependencies might leak into this set-up. Making plugins X, Y and Z depend on XML Utils and IO plugins will add maintenance issues.

Comment: In any case, it generally works. I think there must be some detail that you're leaving out that makes a difference. Have you tried setting up 3 simple plugins with the transitive dependency to verify that it works (that's what I did)?

Comment: Yes, certainly. I am using transitive dependency in my code (with my Common plugin). In this case however something causing this not work. I guess I'll dig a bit deeper to see what is the problem.